# alertView: clickedButtonAtIndex: not called. Other delegate methods get called

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uialertview

That's really weird. I've never seen anything like this. I'm showing an alert view in `UIViewController` category method:

```
  UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:nil];

for(NSString *buttonTitle in otherButtonTitles){
    [alertView addButtonWithTitle:buttonTitle];
}
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kVCActionHandleAlertCancelBlockKey, cancelBlock, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kVCActionHandleAlertOtherBlockKey, otherBlock, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
[alertView show];
```

and `-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` is never called!

But other delegate methods, `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`

and `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` are successfully called! What the heck? Did you ever see anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

The cause was that I had already `-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` defined in my view controller class, but was expecting the same method in category to fire. So the conclusion I think is to never provide delegate methods in categories. It may be dangerous